# Nginx ssl configuration for subdomain

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a website and multiple subdomains. On each subdomain, except one, I use a CMS that generates it's own ssl using Let's Encrypt. On the remaining subdomain I want to add my own certificate from Cloudflare. I generated a certificate put it in my `/var/www/my/` for now. Just for testing. And in nginx I configured this block:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/my/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/my/my.domain.com.key;
    root /var/www/my;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name my.domain.com;
    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/my/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

There seems to be a problem with my implementation because now my.domain.com works but for everything else I get this error from Cloudflare: [Error 525: SSL handshake failed](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200278659-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT:

This is the conf file from the CMS. THis is how they set the certificate.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name sub.domain.com;
    root /var/www/sub/system/nginx-root;

    ssl_certificate /home/domain/.acme.sh/sub.domain.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/domain/.acme.sh/sub.domain.com/sub.domain.com.key;
    include /var/www/sub/system/files/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2369;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

Comment: What about the other server config?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: So `my.domain.com` works and `sub.domain.com` works and rest all subdomains don't work?

Comment: If I add the block for my.domain.com ... my.domain works but everything else doesn't, including sub.domain.com.